# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una fecha de caducidad de una compra en symfony 4?

Tags: symfony4

Mi problema es como puedo agregar una fecha de caducidad de una compra para una página de subastas.

De antemano muchas gracias

Tomé de ejemplo este extracto de código pero no se como adaptarlo correctamente a mi proyecto.

```
<?php
$fechaSistema   = new \DateTime();
$diaInicial     = new \DateTime( '2017-09-01' );// setear tus fechas aqui
$diaEntrega     = new \DateTime( '2017-09-06' );// setear tus fechas aqui

$interval_now       = $fechaSistema->diff($diaEntrega);
$interval_inicial   = $diaInicial->diff($diaEntrega);

$dias_restantes = $interval_now->format('%R%a');
$total_dias     = $interval_inicial->format('%R%a');

if ( $dias_restantes < 0)
{
    // si se ha superado la fecha de entrega
    echo "Ya no tiene garantia";
}
elseif ( $dias_restantes == 0)
{
    // "La garantia vence hoy"
    echo "La garantia vence hoy";
}
else
{
    // "La garantia vence hoy"
    echo 'Queda '.$dias_restantes .' días de garantía.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que si tu proyecto tiene la entidad Compra, podés usar PHP Traits con ORM/Doctrine en la misma. Te dejo [este repositorio](https://github.com/konshensx16/symfony-todo-backend) y [la explicación](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfkiarPlJJ8) del dueño del mismo sobre Traits y como usarlos en entidades. Su ejemplo del código:

```
namespace App\Entity;

trait Timestamps
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function createdAt()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function updateAt()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva!